# How to debug "highly extensible" Winform application without source?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, debugging

I'd want to ask how can I debug application of this kind

There's application X which is highly extensible in that way, that user can load 3rd party extensions (dlls) that e.g open new form window after click on button

So, user(me) loads dll, defines that button A will execute FunctionA() from new dll and it will e.g open new form.

Now I'd want to ask whether is it possible to attach some debugger to running program that will show me code of e.g clicked button **on that window shown by 3rd party dll**?

It's .NET

Comment: What happens if you try to Debug/Attach to Process... ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It's not immediately obvious, what issue you have run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If viewing the source code is enough for you, you can try with IlSpy (https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). This will disassemble .Net IL code into more or less readable code. 
Take into consideration that the disassembled code won't be exactly the same as the source code. During compilation / IL generation some optimizations may occur, or some logic expressions may be altered. So comparing the original code with disassembled code will throw several differences.